# Why does it prints like this

Tags: python-3.x

How does the iteration takes place in the following snippet?

```
a=[0,1,2,3]
b=[]
for a[-1] in a:
    b.append(a[-1])
print(b)

Output is [0,1,2,2]
```

Comment: You're using `a[-1]` (the last entry in `a`) for your iteration variable. So you're setting `a[-1]` to each value in turn.

Comment: What output did you expect? Have you tried to use a debugger to step through the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python `for` loops use assignment which can lead to interesting results if not used correctly.

Your example can be simplified to reflect this better. Since `a[-1]` accesses the last element in `a`, the following code will actually modify `a`:

```
a = [0, 1]
for a[-1] in [9]:
    pass
print(a)
```

outputs

```
[0, 9]
```